# How to post the Drupal contents to Facebook group?

Tags: 7, views, social-network

I want to post the content to facebook groups from a Drupal site. I am able to post the content to Facebook group by using the [Facebook autopost](https://www.drupal.org/project/fb_autopost) module.

How to post the Drupal contents to Facebook group? How can I achieve this functionality? [Facebook autopost](https://www.drupal.org/project/fb_autopost) has not implemented this feature yet.

Comment: Did you find an answer? In your second sentence you say what you ask :-? Looking also for this option - trying to do it with Rules & mail to the group. Every group has a own email.